# Move a range of jobs to another queue with qmove

Tags: bash, batch-processing, hpc, torque

I have several (idle) jobs scheduled on a cluster that I want to move to another queue.

I can move a single job like this (where `1234` is the job id):

```
qmove newQueue 1234
```

But now I have hundreds of jobs that I want to move to newQueue. Is it possible to move them all? Using `*` as a wildcard operator does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the job ids are in sequential order, you could use Bash's *brace extension*. For example:

```
$ echo {0..9}
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Transferred to moving all jobs ranging from 1000 to 2000, the `qmove` command would be:

```
qmove newQueue {1000..2000}
```

This **might** even work if there are job ids that you are not allowed to move (from other users or in running state). They should be simply ignored. *(not tested)*